# Packet capture data into SQL

Tags: c#, .net, database, packet

I was looking around for some tools that help injecting packet capture into a database. I was lucky bu finding one tool from COMMAND FIVE PTY LTD. the tool is called C5 SIGMA, and based on description, it makes possible to get data from capture and put it in a database.

I downloaded files and prepared the environment for run, but when executing, I get a lot of errors

[WARNING] - Unable to convert field value.
    Name: frame.time_relative
    Value: 6.874690000
    Error: Input string was not in a correct format.
[ERROR] - Error processing packet.
    Index: 5179
    Error: Too many asynchronous failures.

I downlaoded source files, and debug, but i found code normal, and parsing is fine. Here is source files: http://www.commandfive.com/downloads/c5sigma.html

If any one could help, I appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded the same product and I get the  Error: Too many asynchronous failures error as well.

I've dropped them an email so if/when I get a response I will let you know.

Just dumped the output to a text file, before all the asynchronous failures is this error:

[ERROR] -     Asynchronous write failure. Error: A network-related or instance-specific 
    error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server w
    as not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is corre
    ct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provide
    r: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Se
    rver)

Might be worth checking to see if your SQL server is expected connections as expected. I'm currently using SQL Express so will try it on a fully fledged SQL server.

Comment: So I've installed SQL Developer 2008 R2 and retried my input and this time it's worked properly. I think the issue may relate to, if you are using a SQL Instance other than "default". This is the command line options I used.

C:\Sigma.exe -ts "c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -in c:\input -out c:\output -dbi -pre Basic -dbh localhost

Answer (score 0):

Actually, had the same issue.  I found by reducing the pcap sizes, C5 Sigma didn't error.